# How do I format html with MathJax after loading it using jQuery.load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mathjax

I am loading a new page with jQuery.load. However, the contents are being treated weirdly somehow. On the original page, I have some code to format latex commands with MathJax:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

And this works fine for the original file. However, when I click on my link and insert more HTML into the page:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link").click(function(){
      $("#myDiv").load("test.html");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Now the special characters are not formatted by MathJax and are just displayed as-is.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Carols 10cents is close, but you need to do the `MathJax.Hub.Queue()` call in a callback from the jQuery `load()` so that the typesetting isn't performed until *after* the file is loaded.  (As it stands, it happens immediately after the file load is requested, even though the file may not be available yet).  Something like

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link").click(function(){
      $("#myDiv").load("test.html", function () {
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "myDiv"]);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

See the [examples](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/talks/2013-01-12.jmm/examples.html) from a talk I gave at the JMM in January 2013 for more details and the solution to other situations.

Answer (score 3):

MathJax only processes markup on page load by default, so you need to tell it to process again after you load the new content onto the page. [The documentation for MathJax for modifying math on the page](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html) recommends, if you only want to process only the new content you added, to do something like:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link").click(function(){
      $("#myDiv").load("test.html");
      MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "myDiv"]);
    });
  });
</script>
```

They mention a few other ways to do this depending on your application, so I recommend reading that page to find the best way for you.

Comment: I added this line but the same is happening.The content is not formatted appropriately.

Comment: Now you need to call `MathJax.typeset()` after the page update. The link to the documentation is helpful