# how to make a svg from jqmath formatted text?

Tags: javascript, svg, jqmath

I discovered jqmath library that works very well.
but now I have a problem:
if I have a formatted text like:

```
<fmath alttext="√^{2}{4}+{1}/{3}" class="fm-inline">
  <mrow>
    <mrow mtagname="mroot">
      <span class="fm-root fm-inline" style="vertical-align: 0.85em;">
        <mn>2</mn>
      </span>
      <mo class="fm-radic">√</mo>
      <span style="vertical-align: 0.086em;">
        <span class="fm-vert fm-radicand" style="border-top-width: 0.072em;">
          <mn>4</mn>
        </span>
      </span>
    </mrow>
      <mo class="fm-infix">+</mo>
      <span mtagname="mfrac" style="vertical-align: 0em;">
        <span class="fm-vert fm-frac">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="fm-num-frac fm-inline">
                  <mn>1</mn>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="fm-den-frac fm-inline">
                  <mn>3</mn>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </span>
      </span>
    </mrow>
  </fmath>
```

can I get or create a SVG file from this.

thanks for help.

Comment: I doubt you can, since it's not svg. Until you want to write your own converter/library for this

Comment: thank you llamerr.

Comment: Note that one problem with SVG is that you can't style it with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is MathML (not SVG surely). jqMath can generate MathML, but not convert it to smth else.

If you want to generate SVG from LaTeX, then you should look at [MathSVG](https://github.com/rajgoel/reveal.js-plugins/tree/master/mathsvg).

If you really want to generate SVG from MathML, you probably have to stack a couple of things. These can be of interest: [MathML to LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85639/i-want-to-convert-mathml-to-latex) and then LaTeX to SVG using MathSVG; [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34924033/convert-latex-mathml-to-svg-or-image-with-mathjax-or-similar); [a tool that's not a web tool but converts MathML to SVG directly](http://pmml2svg.sourceforge.net/doc/user-svg.pdf).