# How do I properly apply <alignment groups; marks> in MATHML?

Tags: html, mathml

The following script is an adaptation of Sandhu ('03) **MathML Handbook**, page 97 – Presentation markup / Controlling alignment (simultaneous equations). The alignment refuses to render in any of the standard browsers including Firefox Quantum (preferred browser Safari). I'm running macOS Sierra on a dual-core system. If you can get the alignment working, please let me know.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<heading>Presentation markup / Tabular math</heading>
<subheading>Simultaneous equations</subheading>
<body>
  <math>
    <mtable>
      <mtr>
        <mtd>
          <mrow>
            <mn>2</mn>
            <mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo>
            <maligngroup/><mi><malignmark/>x</mi>
            <maligngroup/><mo><malignmark/>+</mo>
            <maligngroup/><mi><malignmark/>y</mi>
            <maligngroup/><mo><malignmark/>=</mo>
            <mo>-</mo>
            <maligngroup/><mn><malignmark/>5</mn>
          </mrow>
        </mtd>
      </mtr>
      <mtr>
        <mtd>
          <mrow>
            <maligngroup/><mi><malignmark/>x</mi>
            <maligngroup/><mo><malignmark/>-</mo>
            <mn>2</mn>
            <mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo>
            <maligngroup/><mi><malignmark/>y</mi>
            <maligngroup/><mo><malignmark/>=</mo>
            <maligngroup/><mn><malignmark/>1</mn>
          </mrow>
        </mtd>
      </mtr>
    </mtable>
  </math>
</body>
```

Each equation is placed in a seperate cell of a table consisting of two rows and one column. Five different parts have to be aligned in each equation indepently, so each has five alignment groups and five alignment points. A simplification of this structure is offered on the following page, but the base case first. (Chapter 3.5.5 of the W3C [Mathematical Markup Language (MathML) Version 3.0 2nd Edition](https://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/chapter3.html#presm.malign) text works through an example that is –syntactically– a bit more opulant.)

Here is a very crude block for what the code above should produce (using the `<mspace/>` element):

```html
<html>
  <math>
    <mtable>
      <mtr>
        <mtd>
          <mrow>
            <mn>2</mn>
            <mi>x</mi>
          </mrow>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mo>+</mo>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mrow>
            <mspace width="10px"/>
            <mi>y</mi>
          </mrow>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mo>=</mo>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mrow>
            <mo>-</mo>
            <mn>5</mn>
          </mrow>
        </mtd>
      </mtr>
      <mtr>
        <mtd>
          <mrow>
            <mspace width="5px"/>
            <mi>x</mi>
          </mrow>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mo>-</mo>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mrow>
            <mn>2</mn>
            <mi>y</mi>
          </mrow>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mo>=</mo>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mrow>
            <mspace width="20px"/>
            <mn>1</mn>
          </mrow>
        </mtd>
      </mtr>
    </mtable>
  </math>
</html>
```

Comment: This part of the spec is not supported in any web-oriented renderer.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger thanks for your note. I was just reading through (CoCalc_SageMath)'s documentation to find out how much MathML it handles. Which is the ideal environment for rendering (experimenting with) all of its specifications?

Comment: Okay, I just found the W3C math tools Wiki...

Comment: The wiki and the spec are not maintained. The working group closed in 2016. If you need complex layout on the web, CSS is a better starting point. (But it also lacks such alignment features.)

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger The aim is to transform .xml "MathML" files to SVG (I updated the source script above and I did see your [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34924033/convert-latex-mathml-to-svg-or-image-with-mathjax-or-similar/35430069#35430069) answer on the topic). Currently trying to use pmmL2SVG via Saxon9 processor to that end. Ran into a `main manifest attribute` error message in setting up the JAR. I'll try reaching out to Bert Bos if I can't get it working.

Comment: The answer was about MathJax. If you want to help MathJax get malignmark support, the team might be interested in contributions Just be sure to look at https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-v3/ for the upcoming rewrite.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterKrautzberger.